# Sorting ArrayList by multiple properties

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator

I have an `ArrayList`of players with an attribute of `username` of type string and `winratio` of type long which is just a ratio of `gameswon/gamesplayed*100`.

I want to sort the `ArrayList` by `username` which I have already done using a `Comparator` class, however I also want to make another method that sorts the players based `winratio` and if they have equal `winratio` to order them in terms of their `username`. I am not sure on how to combine the two comparators together and give them a hierarchy so it knows which sort to preference over another.

Thanks

Comment: you can do both the things in single comparator. Just add both the things in single compareTo method'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the difference in `winRatio`, if it is `0`, return the difference in name, for example...

```
public class MultiComparator implements Comparator<Player> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Player o1, Player o2) {
        int result = (int) (o1.getWinRatio() - o2.getWinRatio());
        if (result == 0) {
            result = o1.getUserName().compareTo(o2.getUserName());
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

And because I had nothing to go on, I used this

```
public interface Player {
    public String getUserName();
    public long getWinRatio();
}
```

As the base object

Another (weird) idea might be to create a "chained" `Comparator`, allowing you to take two (or more) `Comparator` and chain them together, so that while the result of any one `Comparator` is `0`, it will keep trying to compare the values to the `Comparator` in the list...

```
public class RatioComparator implements Comparator<Player> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Player o1, Player o2) {
        return (int) (o1.getWinRatio() - o2.getWinRatio());
    }

}

public class NameComparator implements Comparator<Player> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Player o1, Player o2) {
        return o1.getUserName().compareTo(o2.getUserName());
    }

}

public class ChainedComparator implements Comparator<Player> {

    private Comparator<Player>[] comparators;

    public ChainedComparator(Comparator<Player>... comparators) {
        this.comparators = comparators;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Player o1, Player o2) {
        int result = -1;
        for (Comparator<Player> proxy : comparators) {
            result = proxy.compare(o1, o2);
            if (result != 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Which you could use something like...

```
Collections.sort(list, new ChainedComparator(new RatioComparator(), new NameComparator()));
```

This is untested and is just a rough idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be achieved using below code inside compare method,

```
int compare(T o1, T o2){
   if(o1.winratio < o2.winratio){
      return -1;
   }else if(o1.winratio < o2.winratio){
      return +1;
   }else{
     return o1.userName.compareTo(o2.userName);
   }
}
```

This should work, I would suggest implementing Comparable interface for handling default sorting case...

Answer (score -1):

> if they have equal winratio to order them in terms of their username

This indicates that you should use userName for implementing `comparable` (for natural ordering). For winRatio, use `comparator` and in case of equal winRatio - also check their userName.

Comment: @downvoter, you could have waited for the editing to be finished before your precious downvote.